# Podcast Server for Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

I'm searching for an application that can subscribe to podcasts for new episodes and provide them in my home network as local podcasts, so that I can 'subscribe' to the podcast server on the Pi and not the 'real' podcast in the web. This can be useful when a lot of people listen to the same podcasts and use the same network. I know there are a lot of apps that can download new episodes on the Pi (podget, ...) but they only download the mp3 file and that's it. All the other stuff is missing that is downloaded normally together with the episode.

The application "podcast server" is (perhaps) what I'm searching for, but there are a lot of problems running it on the Pi because some of the dependencies are not running on the Raspberry Pi / on arm.

Comment: Please proofread your posts and use capital letters.